# What happens to the cost of the nodes when the graph is converted to its corresponding Line Graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, nodes, graph-theory, edges

I have a graph **G**. I want to convert the graph to its corresponding [Line Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph). The graph **G** has cost associated with its nodes. I want to know how what happens to the cost of the nodes when the graph is converted to the Line Graph.

[image: Look at the image]

Comment: what would you like to do with the cost? My first thought is to convert it to a weight on the edge corresponding to the node - but then there are multiple edges in the line graph for a node in the original.

Comment: I am trying to solve the problem of shortest path when there are turn restrictions imposed on the graph. So, I am converting the graph into its corresponding Line graph. But I am having problems when there are cost associated with only nodes and not edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a graph (with the cost associated to each vertex in `()` brackets:

```
1 (8) ------ 2 (7)
 |  \         |
 |   \        |
 |   3 (9)    |
 |   /        |
 |  /         |
4 (6) ------ 5 (10)
```

You can associate costs to the dual graph by giving the edges in the dual the cost associated with the vertex:

```
          (8)
  [1,2] ------- [1,3]
    | \         /   \
    |  \ (8)   /(8)  \ (9)
    |   \     /       \
(7) |    [1,4] ----- [3,4]
    |         \  (6)  /
    |      (6) \     / (6)
    |           \   /
  [2,5] ------- [4,5]
          (10)
```

So the connection `[1,4]` to `[3,4]` goes through the vertex `4` which has an associated cost of `6` so the edge in the dual representing this gets a cost of `6`.